# Why is my custom HashMap class, which extends HashMap, not properly working for put?

Tags: java, enums, hashmap

I'm working on some code in which I have a custom HashMap class which extends HashMap.

**Custom HashMap Class**

```
public class CaseInsensitiveMap<T> extends HashMap<String, T> {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public T put(String key, T value) {
    return super.put(key.toLowerCase(), value);
 }

 public T get(String key) {
    return super.get(key.toLowerCase());
 }
}
```

My enum creates the class as a lookup and puts all the values. The put statement does not work correctly in that it overwrites values and the values don't fill in the HashMap table but instead skips indexes.

**Enum**

```
public enum UpdateMode{
/**
 * No auto-updates or update notifications will occur. Updates can be performed manually.
 */
UNAVAILABLE("UNAVAILABLE", false),
/**
 * Updates are enabled and the driver will be notified only once per session.
 */
AVAILABLE("AVAILABLE", true),
/**
 * The device will be forced to update with no user notification.
 */
MANDATORY("MANDATORY", true);

private final String code;
private final boolean isAutomatic;

private UpdateMode(String code, boolean isAutomatic)
{
    this.code = code;
    this.isAutomatic = isAutomatic;
}

//private static final CaseInsensitiveMap<UpdateMode> lookup = new CaseInsensitiveMap<UpdateMode>();
private static final HashMap<String, UpdateMode> lookup = new HashMap<String, UpdateMode>();

static {
    for (final UpdateMode t : UpdateMode.values()) {
        lookup.put(t.code(), t);
    }
}

/**
 * Gets the enum from the supplied code string value.
 * @param code
 * @return
 */
public static UpdateMode get(String code) {
    if (lookup.containsKey(StringUtil.nullToEmptyString(code))) {
        return lookup.get(code);
    }

    return AVAILABLE;
}


/**
 * Returns the code value of the UpdateModes ("UNAVAILABLE", "AVAILABLE", "MANDATORY")
 * @return
 */
public String code()
{
    return code;
}


/**
 * Checks if update features are automatic.
 *
 * @return true, if is automatic
 */
public boolean isAutomatic() {
    return isAutomatic;
}
```

}

This fails because when using the Custom HashMap class, the "UpdateMode" is not found because that value was replaced by another string value.

```
        // Automated updates have been disabled.
    if (!updateServiceContext.getUpdateMode().isAutomatic())
    {
        return;
    }
```

When I use HashMap directly everything works as expected and the HashMap table fills with all my values. Why is my custom HashMap class not properly filling by the put?

Pictures of the values in the table for the HashMap. Notice the difference when using the custom HashMap class vs using the HashMap directly. Not all the put values are there and there are gaps in the table.

**Custom HashMap Class Which Extends HashMap**

[image: Custom class HashMap]

**Java HashMap**

[image: Using standard HashMap]

Comment: *it overwrites values and the values don't fill in the HashMap table bottom up but instead skips indexes.* These are meaningless words. What are you trying to say?

Comment: "fills from the bottom up" - what are you talking about? "bottom"? HashMaps don't have a bottom. Are you looking at the backing array in a debugger? If so, why?

Comment: Even if you get this working, I'm not sure that this extension is a good idea.  For a start, you haven't overriden several other methods (e.g. `putAll`), leading to inconsistent behaviour.  Users will also find the behaviour of e.g. `keySet()` confusing...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Not quite up on my lingo. I've added images of what I am seeing. The image for Custom shows that only 2 key/values were added even though the for loop executed 3 times. One of the values was overwritten. Also, there are gaps in the table. As opposed to the Standard HashMap which has all 3 values and has no gaps in the table.

Comment: `HashMap` makes no ordering guarantees, and the internal hashtable implementation can put entries wherever it wants. Unless you're seeing a behavioral problem there's no reason to pay any attention to internal data.

Comment: That makes sense. The issue I am seeing is that using the custom HashMap class overwrites the first entry it puts into it and hence bugs show up in code that rely on checking that value. When I use the standard HashMap everything works fine. I'm at my wits end because I was instructed to use the custom HashMap class.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] with example data which works with `HashMap`, but not with your version. And also tell us what problem you have. You said, some values get overwritten, but do you know that by checking the value assigned to the key (the value changes) or by looking at the internal hashtable again?

Comment: You're still being very vague about your problem. *[T]he custom HashMap class overwrites the first entry it puts into it and hence bugs show up in code that rely on checking that value.* What was the first entry? How do you know it was overwritten? What was it overwritten by? What bugs are showing up? What value are they checking? What are they checking it for?

Comment: The `CaseInsensitiveMap`just fills fine with all three enum values when i run your code

Comment: What is the implementation of `getUpdateMode()`, and what behavior are you seeing *in the code that uses the map*, not in the map's internals? The debugger screenshots you show are of internal implementation details that should be irrelevant to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best guess: In `getUpdateMode()`, either the declared type of the map there is some superclass, not `CaseInsensitiveMap`, or the value you pass to `get()` is not declared as a `String`. In either case, it will invoke the `HashMap` version of `get()`, not your override, which does not lowercase the string and thus fails because it's looking for `"UpdateMode"` when the stored key is `"updatemode"`.

This is because your override of `get()` is actually *not* an override, because its declared parameter type is different. `Map.get()` is declared to take an `Object`, not a `K`, and any override of it must do the same. Change your override of `get()` to this:

```
public T get(Object key) {
    if (!(key instanceof String)) {
        return null;
    }
    return super.get(((String) key).toLowerCase());
}
```

If you had used the `@Override` annotation on each of your overrides, you would have gotten a compiler warning telling you about this.

Comment: Thank you for seeing through all of my misinformation that I seemed to be so focused on. This indeed was the case and I've got everything working now.